# Custom User login in AppEngine

Tags: authentication, gae-userservice

I have a Java Servlet backend with a datastore connected to my app; I am trying to implement a login system using the Android Studio LoginActivity template, using the user's email and password (not the PlusBaseActivity handling the Google Account login), but I don't know how to proceed from here:

How can you say that a User is logged in? and how can I make it so persistently using my datastore? I've read here: [How to login User using UserService on AppEngine Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831847/how-to-login-user-using-userservice-on-appengine-java) that I just need to call the method `resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()))`, and I've done so:

```
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
      int size = checkDatastore(); // 0 if empty, > 0 if not empty
      if(size==0){
          populateDatastore();
      }

      String asyncMessage = req.getParameter("order");

      if(asyncMessage.equals("login")){
          mail = req.getParameter("email");
          psw = req.getParameter("password");

          UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
          User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

          String message="";
          resp.setContentType("text/plain");
          PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
          if(user == null) {

             //Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the
             // specified redirect location URL and clears the buffer.
             String uri = userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI());
             resp.sendRedirect(uri);
             User user1 = userService.getCurrentUser();
             message="No one is logged in!\n" + "Sent from App Engine at " + new Date();

            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }if(user !=null) {
            //  login(user);
            message = "Hello, " + user.getEmail() +
                    ", "+user.getNickname()+"!" + "\nSent from App Engine at "+ new Date();

            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

but the `sendRedirect()` method only gives me a URI. What for?

Moreover, the `User user = userService.getCurrentUser()` always returns `null`. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()))`
of UserService only works when integrating the Login with Google Accounts as shown in [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/#Java_User_authentication_in_Java) documentation. 
If you want to implement a personalised login system you can do that in many ways. Surely you will need a Servlet checking new users' data and a datastore to persistently store new account registrations.